# Robocopy script that created folder in destination with date

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, robocopy

I'm trying to write a script that copies a folder every week night. I would like it to create a folder each night in the destination directory.

So I'm trying to make a script that copies 
"C:\logs" to "I:\logs\today's date"

So the destination folder should look like this

"I:\logs\Monday_1272014"
then the next night it should look like this 
"I:\logs\Tuesday_1282014"

and so on for each weekday. I'm not sure if I'm making sense, but any help would be appreciated.

So far I have this for the Robocopy script:
robocopy "E:\Batch Files" "I:\Backups\Monday" /MIR

But that would just create a folder named Monday. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, it does not have to be robocopy. I just use that because it's the only one I know. I wouldn't mind learning how to do it as a batch file or VB Script.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the naming convention used by the log files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first four lines of this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%"
```

Alter the order of `%yyyy%` and `%mm%` and `%dd%` to suit you and then you can add the variable to Robocopy:

```
robocopy "E:\Batch Files" "I:\Backups\%datestamp%" /MIR
```

Comment: 2014/01/28 00:14:10 ERROR 267 (0x0000010B) Creating Destination Directory I:\Bac
kups\%dt:~4,2%DD%YYYY\
The directory name is invalid.

Comment: You mucked up the variables.  Evidently you have XP Home which doesn't support WMIC.

Comment: Got it to work. I had to change: for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a" to for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%a"

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 PRO x64

Comment: I got the script to work, but now I have another issue. I saved it as test_script.bat .When I double click the .bat file, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? I'm running Windows 7 Pro x64. I put the file in notepad and did "save as" "all files" and named it "test_script.bat"

Comment: Eureka!!! I got it figured out. When I wanted to just type the script into the cmd window I had to change %%a to %a. However, when i wanted to save it as a .bat file I have to change it back to %%a.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%a IN (Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday) DO SET /a cnt+=1&SET "DOW!cnt!=%%a"
FOR /f "tokens=1-4" %%a in ('wmic path win32_currenttime get Day^,Month^,Year^,DayOfWeek^|findstr /v "^$"') DO (
    IF %%a LEQ 9 (SET "Day=0%%a") ELSE SET "Day=%%a"
    IF %%c LEQ 9 (SET "Month=0%%c") ELSE SET "Month=%%c"
    SET "Year=%%d"
    SET "DayOfWeek=%%b"
)
ECHO(ROBOCOPY "E:\Batch Files" "I:\logs\!DOW%DayOfWeek%!_%Day%%Month%%Year%" /MIR
```

This doesn't work in XP Home.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, it wont let me paste the output...too many characters.

Comment: How did you paste the screen shot?

Comment: Just click on the picture icon.